# Android: building different versions of my app (free, premium, etc.) with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

With my current code base I'd like to build two or more different versions of my Android app (free, premium, ...). For the iPhone (XCode) I can definte different targets. Is there something similar implemented in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's such functionality in Eclipse (or the Android plug-in for it). Though using ant you should be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

For my builds I have set up in Eclipse my projects using Maven and the [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/). This allows you to depend on the apksources of other projects and override the code and resources of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Library projects - supported in Eclipse - here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject